# Is there a way to publish web content and simply make a profit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I envision something like S3 (Amazon Simple Storage Solution), but where the content creator gets to set a price per download, and assign which Amazon accounts receive which percentage of the revenue.

It'd be great if the content creator could set their cut at zero, and then whoever is downloading the asset is paying exactly and only for the S3 download bandwidth.

Or if the content creator could estimate how many downloads they would get in a month, schedule cost amortization for the S3 storage cost as well, and build that right in to the download cost.  If the actual download rate is much different, perhaps the amortized cost could be configured to adjust itself rapidly, slowly, etc.

Or if the content creator could set up an asset to pay for its own storage and bandwidth, with some initial allowance.  As soon as the asset has a negative balance, the asset could be immediately deleted, so as not to incur any more costs to the creator.  Or the creator could pre-empt this death, and withdraw revenue at any time.

And if you put that all together, the content creator could say, "Amortize the storage cost (1k downloads per month expected, but adjust at a medium pace), die when it runs out of money, but I want to make $0.10 off every download, $0.01 of that to stay with the asset to pay for its own storage during lean months, $0.01 of that should go to my editor's account, and the other $0.08 go to me."

And yes, Amazon might demand their cut for doing all of this processing.

If I'm playing a video game, and click to download a new map, some Amazon API could be used to ask me to confirm my purchase, and then download the asset.  All *completely transparently* to the person who created the map.

If I'm browsing the web, an "are you sure, this costs $0.30" interstitial page could open, before allowing me to download.  All hidden behind a simple URL.

My point being that if this were built right in to S3, rather than requiring an entire storefront and Credit Card processing, etc, this would make it trivially easy for content creators to share and profit from their work.

Does such a thing already exist?

Comment: The closest thing is Requester Pays Buckets on S3. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html Also, this question doesn't really seem programming related.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I couldn't decide on a better place to ask it.  Also, I'd love it if something like this already existed, so as a Game Developer, I could make an interface to download new levels, and use a trivially simple API, and boom - I'm making money as long as people are downloading my level!  It's like an instant Asset Store.

Comment: And my problem with "Requester Pays" is that I'm stuck paying for storage costs, and there's no way to add more charges on top of that.  I end up having to build a huge amount of infrastructure (an "Asset Store"), just to protect and profit from my assets.

Comment: Well you are looking at a low level file storage system and wanting it to do things like credit card payments for in-game level downloads. I think you need to be looking at something specific to your use case (games) that is purpose built to handle that sort of thing. Something like Google Play services or Steam or whatever works with the platform you are developing your game for.

Comment: While interesting and well-written, this is off-topic (for one of several reasons). I simply chose "Too Broad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are already using S3 - you can leverage `Amazon DevPay` to charge back your customer.

Your customers doesn't required to be on AWS or have AWS account - Amazon.com account is sufficient.

Currently DevPay is supported for EC2 and S3.

Info from [Amazon docs](https://aws.amazon.com/devpay/faqs/)

> Q: What is Amazon DevPay?
>
> Amazon DevPay is a simple-to-use online billing and account management
>   service that makes it easy for businesses to sell applications that
>   are built in, or run on top of, Amazon Web Services. It is designed to
>   make running applications in the cloud and on demand easier for
>   developers.
>
> Amazon DevPay removes the pain of having to create or manage your own
>   order pipeline or billing system, which is traditionally a challenge
>   for online subscription services or applications running on demand. It
>   allows you to quickly sign up customers, automatically meter their
>   usage of AWS services, have Amazon bill them based on the prices you
>   set, and collect payments. Amazon DevPay provides a simple web
>   interface for pricing your application based on any combination of
>   up-front, recurring and usage-based fees. It uses Amazon Payments to
>   process payments from your customers, and lets you leverage Amazon’s
>   trusted billing infrastructure, making it easy for tens of millions of
>   Amazon customers to pay for your application using their existing
>   Amazon accounts